# In the prepositional phrase, "from the ground up," does "up" function as a preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, capitalization

I want to know, if I make the title of an essay "From the Ground Up," should the "Up" really be capitalized? Typically, unless they are the first word in a title, prepositions are not capitalized. I think "ground" would be the object of the preposition, "from." I'm just not sure what that makes "Up."

Comment: Yes, because it is meaningful in the idiom and not therefore a "little word" like "and" and "the".

Comment: Research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case#:~:text=Capitalize%20the%20first%20and%20the,of%20four%20letters%20or%20fewer.

Comment: More like an adverb, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an adverb. ([Up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) can be an adjective, adverb, noun, preposition, or verb.) You could substitute "[upwards](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upwards)", "skywards", etc, with the same meaning and grammar, and they are unambiguously adverbs.

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact answer I was looking for, because I am simply following the rules of capitalization based on whether it is a preposition, article, or conjunction. If it isn't, and it's not the first word, then I don't capitalize it. Since "up" is an adverb, this tells me that it should, in fact, be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know or care about whether the cited usage is a preposition or not. The underlying question is whether or not to *capitalize*. And the best way to answer that is to see [what other writers and publishers have done in the past...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=From%20the%20Ground%20up%2CFrom%20the%20Ground%20Up&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

Note that Google NGrams is case-sensitive. I capitalized the words ***From*** and ***Ground***, so I assume almost 100% of the matches for both search terms (***...up*** and ***...Up***) will be "titles". Obviously whatever you call "up" here (preposition, "little word",...), people normally ***do*** capitalize it in such contexts.

Comment: How do we know that your results are titles??

Comment: Go and have a look. I'm not gonna bother, because as I said in the answer, I think the fact that I capitalized From and Ground means they'll almost all be "titles". So please don't waste my time if you find one or two that *aren't*, unless you can show that *most* of the matches aren't titles.

Comment: How do you see the actual results and not just the use lines over time?

Comment: You can't see the "actual" results from case-sensitive query strings. My chart doesn't include the possibility of "drilling down" to the results with lower-case "up" because there aren't enough of them. But if there *were* enough, drilling down would produce exactly the same results for "...up" and "...Up" because Google Books (unlike NGrams) *isn't* case-sensitive. But you can just leaf through as many as you like of the hundreds / thousands of results by clicking on "**<**" at bottom left of the chart underneath "Search in Google Books".

Comment: I know that I can't see them in the query strings. I didn't see the stuff une Google Books easily but  now by jiggling my screen I can. Thanks.

Comment: I must admit I find [*this* chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Leagues+Under+the+Sea%2CLeagues+under+the+Sea&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for the string "**leagues Under / under the Sea**" a little surprising. I can only assume the "far from insignificant" showing for the (obviously incorrect, imho) lower case ***under*** is because lots of people share OP's misconception that the applicability of the label "preposition" is the determining factor. Your comment astutely avoids mentioning that, in favour of the contextually useful "little words"!

Comment: ...in which context it was interesting to do a Google ***image*** search for "leagues under the sea". As youi'd expect, image search finds a lot of movie posters, etc. Most of which are *entirely* in capital letters, but I checked at least a couple of dozen that had mixed case. The NGram shows maybe 30% of all instances have the "erroneous" lower-case ***under***, but I didn't see a single example of that from "publicists" material (which I'd trust far more than random occurrences in general text, that might just be reported speech clumsily transcribed).

Comment: I am not going to read all that. It's just too much, FF.

Comment: Well, I take it we both agree that "under" is definitely a preposition in its own right in *20,000 Leagues Under the Sea*, but in *that* context, there's no real question of not capitalizing it (even if the NGram isn't as "definitive" as I'd have liked / expected). So it *should* be enough to convince the OP that te "preposition" label isn't a major factor in title capitalization.

Comment: For that book, it's better to just google it but under would be capitalized of course. But not the the just as you posted.